# Why does padding make my Tkinter widget longer?

Tags: tkinter

I have a button with a background colour of grey. I add some pady and the button somehow got longer. Is that what the height parameter does?

```
from tkinter import *


class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        self.geometry("1200x700")
        self.main()
    def main(self):
        self.button = Button(self, pady=100, background="red")

window = Window()

window.mainloop()
```

I was trying to fix it, but every time it had errors.

Comment: It is better to post the full error traceback.  It is expected that `pady=100` will make the button taller, so what do you expected actually on `pady=100` instead? Note that you have forgot to call `super().__init__()` inside `Window.__init__()` and layout function on `self.button` inside `main()`.

Comment: It looks like the use of `pady` is doing exactly what it's documented to do. What do you expect it to do that's different from what it's doing?

Answer (score -2):

The `Button(self,...` This created too many error. Remove `self` will fix problem.
self.geometry("1200x700")...  this may

```
 [Previous line repeated 792 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Also missing is pack for Button.

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *


class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
         
        self.main()
    def main(self):
        self.button = Button(background="red")
        self.button.pack(pady=100)


root = Tk()
window = Window()
root.geometry("1200x700")
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]